# firebase_ui_firestore not paginating

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

```
    class Asd extends StatelessWidget {
  const Asd({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FirestoreListView(
      loadingBuilder: (context) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
      pageSize: 3,
      emptyBuilder: (context) {
        return const Center(
          child: Text('No data'),
        );
      },
      query: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(Constants.blogCollection)
          .where('isApproved', isEqualTo: true)
          .orderBy("createdAt", descending: true)
          .withConverter(fromFirestore: (snapshot, options) {
        return Blog.fromMap(snapshot.data()!);
      }, toFirestore: (blog, options) {
        return blog.toMap();
      }),
      itemBuilder: (context, doc) {
        final blog = doc.data();
        print("blog: $blog");
        return PostCard(
          blog: blog,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I wrote my code as stated, but when I look at the console, I see that all the data in the database came instead of 3 items.I'm using the firebase_firestore_ui package. When I scroll down on my emulator, I don't see the circular progress indicator and it's all there.

Answer (score 0):

How did you determine that the [FirebaseUI `FirestoreListView`](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/ui/firestore/#usage) isn't working?

Keep in mind that `FirestoreListView` implements infinite scroll and **not** explicit pagination. So it loads the items as needed, which means that it list the number of items needed to fill the page and then loads more items as needed.

So if you scroll down to the bottom of your list it will indeed end up loading all documents from the collection. But if instead you only stay on the first screenfull of documents, it will only load the first set of documents.

Comment: Since I saw all the blogs in the console, I assumed that you read them all, then can I say that the document has not been read as much as I see it in the console? Does it make sense if I make page size 1, my items are already loaded below

Comment: It needs to load enough documents to fit the space that the widget occupies in your UI. The default from the docs seems that it does that in increments of 10 documents. So if the UI allows for 5 items, it'll load 10 documents. If the UI allows for 11 items, it'll load 20 documents.